# PromQL multi join

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

okay, this is not a simple PromQL query that i want to run. this is my input data:

```
accessPoint_numClients{mac="00:11:22:33:44:55"} 11
accessPoint_numClients{mac="00:11:22:33:44:AA"} 12
accessPoint_numClients{mac="00:11:22:33:44:BB"} 5

accessPoints{mac="00:11:22:33:44:55", groupId="1"} 1
accessPoints{mac="00:11:22:33:44:AA", groupId="1"} 1
accessPoints{mac="00:11:22:33:44:BB", groupId="2"} 1

controller_zone_groups{groupId="1", groupName="Foo"} 1
controller_zone_groups{groupId="2", groupName="Bar"} 1
controller_zone_groups{groupId="3", groupName="Baz"} 1
```

so, i want generate an grafana graph that group client-count by groups and also print out the related groupNames.

so this is my current try, but this is far away from an working query:

```
sum by (groupId) (accessPoint_numClients * on (mac) group_left(groupId) accessPoints * on (groupId) group_left(groupName) controller_zone_groups)
```

is there any chance to get this working?

thx, volker...

================ UPDATE ===============

okay, maybe some sample querys with response:

```
sum by (apGroupId) ((smartzone_accessPoint_numClients * on (mac) group_left(apGroupId) smartzone_accessPoints) or (groupId) group_left(groupName) smartzone_controller_zone_groups)
```

==> "parse error at char 125: unexpected  in aggregation, expected \")\""

```
sum by (apGroupId) (smartzone_accessPoint_numClients * on (mac) group_left(apGroupId) smartzone_accessPoints) * on (apGroupId) group_left(groupName) smartzone_controller_zone_groups
```

==> "many-to-many matching not allowed: matching labels must be unique on one side"

```
sum by (groupName) (smartzone_accessPoint_numClients * on (mac) group_left(apGroupId) smartzone_accessPoints) * on (apGroupId) group_left(groupName) smartzone_controller_zone_groups
```

==> "many-to-many matching not allowed: matching labels must be unique on one side"

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, but I think what you're asking for is why `groupName` isn't in the output. The answer is that the `sum` aggregates it away, which adding `groupName` to the `by` will fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like the following:

```
sum by (groupName) (
  sum by (groupId) (
    accessPoint_numClients * on(mac) group_right(groupId) accessPoints
  ) * on(groupId) group_right(groupName) controller_zone_groups
)
```